# Clan wars in clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

What would happen if I left my clan during battle day and came back still during battle day? Would I still be able to attack?

Answer (score 2):

## Going Idle during a war and coming back

Simple answer, is yes you can.

Clash of Clans can't force you to stay on your device! You can get off, get some coffee, go have a drive, come back and still be able to battle!

Excerpt from the FAQ:

> **What happens if someone in my clan isn’t active in a war?**
>   Inactive members are treated the same as active members in clan wars. They can still be the target of any actions during the war, including receiving donated troops and being attacked by the enemy. Inactive members will still count toward the total team size and their war bases will still appear on the war map. However, inactive members will not use their attacks and will not receive any bonus loot. **(Obviously because their idle)**
>   As long as you still fit the requirements to battle, you can. At anytime (during the battle day).

---

## Leaving clan and coming back during a war

Well, this on the other hand, you should never do.

**If** you leave during **prep day** and come back **before** battle day, no deductions are counted.

**If** you leave during **battle day**, you get no loot or bonuses **at all**, and obtain a shiny two day cooldown to be fight-able again.

(As proved [**here**](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/246529-What-happens-if-you-leave-your-clan-while-in-a-clan-war))

> If you leave during prep day and join back, nothing changes
>   **(Prep day)**
>
> ---
>
> Nothing. No credit for the win. No war bonus loot. And 2 day cooldown before your eligible for another war.
>   **(Battle day)**

So be **very** careful what you decide.

---

See [**here**](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ) for Frequently Asked Questions on this topic.

Comment: I believe you misinterpreted the question. I think he wants to leave his clan an maybe join another in the meantime, then join his original clan again and fight in the war. AFAIK you have to be enlisted in a clan during preparation day to participate in a clan war.

Comment: @Ahhhh! Yes! I understand. I was basing it **entirely** due to the fact that he goes ***idle***. Shall I edit my answer?

Comment: @kasoban Done. Added in.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you make it back before the war is done, you can still attack. The first time I did that, i was pretty scared that i wouldn't get my attacks, but i was still able to attack

Answer (score 1):

### Leaving clan and coming back during a war

According to the [FAQ](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ) you can leave your clan, rejoin and partake in the ongoing war.

> **What happens if I leave a clan during a clan war?**
>
> After a leader or co-leader presses the “Start War” button, you are free to leave, join other clans and return to the clan to continue participating in the clan war. Your war base will remain in the war map even if you leave, so leaving a clan will not affect an ongoing war.
>
> However, you cannot participate in more than one clan war at a time. If you leave a clan while participating in a clan war, you will not be able to participate in any other clan wars until that previous war has ended. Other players will be able to see that you are still part of an unfinished war by checking your profile. You will be marked as ineligible for war until the previous clan war has concluded.
>
> **Can I still participate in the Clan War if I leave the current clan?**
>
> Yes you can still participate, but you have to rejoin that clan first.

---

### Leaving before the war ends

For all things war related you stay a war participant until the war ends. If you attack and leave your clan before the war ends you will even get your war loot bonus.

> **What happens to my War Loot if I leave my clan before the end of the war?**
>
> Your War Loot will be delivered to your Clan Castle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still raid.

Clash of Clans does not have a cooldown for when you can raid in a clan raid after you have joined a clan. <--- May not be clear. What I'm saying is that you do not have to wait to be able to participate in clan events.

Answer (score -1):

If you leave and and join before the battle day ends you will still be able to attack in the on-going war unless you are not a part of the war.