# Can I join a war in a new clan if I leave during the prep day in my old clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I joined a war with a clan that is full of nuts/inappropriate people. After starting war they kicked out a few people who are already in war in their clan. So my clan surely gonna lose. I am in war now. If I choose to leave the Clan now during the preparation day and join another clan, will I be able to war in my new clan? Or I have to wait till the war at my previous/current clan ends?

Comment: did you made any comment? as i got in mobile notification but in site there is no comment.

Comment: Yes, just thanks. 
One more thing was that I didnt wanted to continue with my current clan. Should I just click the I'M out in Clan wars will opt me out of any next wars?

Comment: yes, if you will click on I'M out in clan wars then you won't be in next clan till you will not change it..but still you will be in clan.. if  you don't want to be in clan then leave the clan.

Comment: @MdMehmudSiddiqueTwin If you select "I'm out", the leader/co-leader initiating the war can still put you in the war.

Comment: @Jerry do you mean leader can put in next war! Even though I selected "Im out" ?

Comment: @MdMehmudSiddiqueTwin Yes

Comment: This question is not really duplicate of the other. The other questions has answer to this one, because the answerer answered more than what was asked. But the related question is really about something else, so I think this question here should not be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't join war in new clan till last one ends and your town will be remained in last clan map so new clan memeber will know that you were in war but did not attack. Read [here](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ) for more detail.

But if you will leave clan and then will join old clan back before war ends then you can use your attack.

Read more [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201699/clan-wars-in-clash-of-clans)

**What happens if I leave a clan during a clan war?**

After a leader or co-leader presses the “Start War” button, you are free to leave, join other clans and return to the clan to continue participating in the clan war. Your war base will remain in the war map even if you leave, so leaving a clan will not affect an ongoing war.

However, you cannot participate in more than one clan war at a time. If you leave a clan while participating in a clan war, you will not be able to participate in any other clan wars until that previous war has ended. Other players will be able to see that you are still part of an unfinished war by checking your profile. You will be marked as ineligible for war until the previous clan war has concluded.

**Can I still participate in the Clan War if I leave the current clan?**

Yes you can still participate, but you have to rejoin that clan first.

Hope you will get your answer or let me know if you have any question. Thanx